# Redirect with ID that was just created

Tags: vb.net, redirect

I need to redirect my page based off of the ID that was just created.
This is my insert statement that generates the ID that I will need to fetch for the redirect.

```
'SQL Insert: Product table
   Dim sqlInsertProduct As String = "INSERT INTO Product 
                                    (ProductName, Status, CreateDate, ModifyDate, 
                                    CreateUser, ModifyUser, Price) 
                                    VALUES (@ProductName, @Status ,getdate(),
                                    getdate(), @CreateUser, @ModifyUser, @Price)
                                    ;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
   Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlInsertProduct, cn)
    Dim ProductID As String
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductName", txtNewProductName.Text))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", StatusCheckbox.Checked))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Price", txtPrice.Text))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CreateUser",
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ModifyUser",
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
    cn.Open()
    ProductID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
 End Using

Response.Redirect("Product/Default.aspx?id=" + ProductID)
```

The Response.Redirect is all the way at the bottom of the page after 3 other inserts into 3 different tables. The only thing I can think of to make this work is to put the redirect into that using, but I can't because I need the other tables to get inserted into and it wouldn't make sense to redirect before the rest of the inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored the ProductID into a session and used that for the redirect.

```
Dim sqlInsertProduct As String = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Status, CreateDate,   
                                  ModifyDate, CreateUser, ModifyUser, Price) 
                                  VALUES (@ProductName, @Status,
                                  getdate(),getdate(), @CreateUser, @ModifyUser,
                                  @Price);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlInsertProduct, cn)
            Dim ProductID As String
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductName", txtNewProductName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", StatusCheckbox.Checked))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Price", txtPrice.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CreateUser",
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ModifyUser",
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            cn.Open()
            ProductID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Session("ProductID") = ProductID
            Dim Product As String = Session("ProductID")
        End Using
        cn.Close()
```

*****other inserts on the page*****

```
Response.Redirect("Product/Default.aspx?id=" + Session("ProductID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` returning your inserted Id. e.g.

```
Dim sqlInsertProduct As String = "INSERT INTO Product 
                                     (ProductName, Status, CreateDate, ModifyDate,
                                     CreateUser, ModifyUser, Price) 
                                     VALUES (@ProductName, @Status ,getdate(),
                                     getdate(), @CreateUser, @ModifyUser, @Price); 
                                     SELECT @@IDENTITY AS InsertID;
```

...

```
Dim ProductID as String = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Response.Redirect("Product/Default.aspx?id=" & ProductID)
```

Comment: I would if I could but I spent a long time researching `OUTPUT` and I don't get it. Is `OUTPUT` the only way I can do this redirect?

Comment: You don't need to use `OUTPUT`. Just execute the query above assigning the return value to a variable. ExecuteScalar will return the first column of the first row, and in this case you will only be returning one value.  You would be passing in two queries.  One to insert and one to grab the last inserted identity.

Comment: I edited above with the ExecuteScalar() but my application can't see ProductID. I think it might be because the connection is closed shortly after the inserts since there are inserts into other tables on this page.

Comment: You still have to add the additional `SELECT @@IDENTITY` into your original query.

Comment: Oh oops, yeah I have `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after that INSERT statement. I still get blue squiggles under ProductID in the Response.Redirect saying that it isn't declared. It also says it's hidden in an enclosing block.

Comment: shouldnt use @@IDENTITY.  Its deprecated.  should now use SCOPE_IDENTITY().  You can read about the differences on google.

Comment: @Boo, I'm using SCOPE_IDENTITY, I just forgot to mention that in the first post. I have updated the original post.

Comment: @George The only place Visual Studio will let me put that Redirect is in the Using for that particular INSERT statment. I really need it at the end of the page so that my other 3 INSERTS will have the chance to function.